# Автоматический перенос строк

Tags: html, css

У меня такая ерунда, при длинном тексте без переносов, таблица растягивается до необычайных размеров.
[image]

Как решить эту проблему с помощью CSS?

Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте 
    word-wrap: break-word;

Answer (score 2):

первое, что пришло в голову: задать размеры блока с текстом. ну а второе `overflow: hidden`

Answer (score 1):

да, действительно проще всего обернуть контент в блок  тут будет контент  и придать блоку свойства допустим так:
**код в css**

```
#rama     
border: 1px solid #faa20a;
padding: 10px 10px;
margin: 10px 15px 20px 15px;
width:400px;
height: 600px;
overflow: auto;
```

вот где-то так у тебя получится блок 400х600 с внутренними отступами и даже с прокруткой, в случае если содержимое (контент) будет вылезать за его пределы.

Comment: по-моему прокрутка не есть круто кода нужен перенос))